# compiler: Algorithm to handle ORG statements that cause data overlaps

Tags: assembly, memory, overwrite, corruption, 8051

I'm currently doing microcontroller programming and one statement I use often (particularly when defining interrupt vectors and start of the program) is the ORG statement. It indicates at which point in code memory data insertion takes place.

Now what really frustrates me is that when I sometimes do programming and my program fails to work, I normally look at other functions first for errors then I finally come to the realization after using a debugging tool that wrong code is overwriting other code.

Here's an example of a trouble situation in code format in generic assembler. Also assume it has a function that allows contents of a file to be included:

```
INCLUDE somefile.asm

ORG 0h
jmp maincode

ORG 1000h
;beginning of interrupt vector

maincode:
;enable interrupt
;beginning of main code here
```

Ideally what the program should do is jump to the "maincode" area of memory and run that code, then if an interrupt happens then jump to address 1000h. In the interrupt vector, it can jump to another area of memory then afterwards it returns to the area of the main program in which the interrupt was called from.

Now things can get problemmatic if the file somefile.asm contains actual code that is part of the program because that actual code will be overwritten just because of the ORG statements shown. This results in program corruption.

I'm using 8051 assembly compiler for my microcontroller (the ASEM-51 macro assembler) and I checked its options for prevention of overlapping data and it doesn't have such option, so I plan to write code in C to overcome this.

**Idea**

What I have come up with for an idea so far which is rather crude is to make the program read data and for each ORG statement it comes across, assemble to that point and if there's no error then run the macro assembler again and continue until no more ORG statements are found.

Because my program will have at least one or two interrupt handlers, that means I'll have to make a program that runs the macro assembler at least 3x. one for each ORG statement.

Instead of running the compiler so many times, is there a better approach in terms of programming to use to make sure parts of my code don't overlap with other parts when doing the final compilation to binary?

I'm not asking for a specific program, but I am asking for an algorithm. a good answer in pseudo code will be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use a linker to place your code, rather than ORG?

Comment: No because I'm working almost at the lowest level possible. The lowest I could go is manual byte-for-byte insertion with a hex editor which I'm not willing to do

Comment: Can you avoid ORG directives in files you're going to `include`, so only one file has all the ORG directives controlling the layout?  Otherwise I'd agree with prl: the technology to solve this problem was invented long ago; it's called a linker and it works by having different asm files place code in sections, and the linker joins the same section from multiple object files.